# 'Row value misused' when inserting an array of structs into database

Tags: sql, go, psql, go-gorm

The following insert query resulted in `row value misused` error (query generated by `golang gorm`):

```
INSERT INTO employees_details (img_uid, img_files) 
VALUES 
  (
    "asfe123y3uygy43", 
    (
      "{\"ImageID\":\"ISDx-Y0fudfhv4lC_M25j\",\"ImageType\":\"original\",\"MediaType\":\"img/png\",\"MediaPath\":\"it-profile/faergbgbder34fgb/original/154895123-owen.png\"}", 
      "{\"ImageID\":\"fgsrtbrdsthrb\",\"ImageType\":\"thumbnail\",\"MediaType\":\"img/png\",\"MediaPath\":\"it-profile/faergbgbder34fgb/thumb/154895123-owen.png\"}"
    )
  )
```

The column `img_files` is a column containing an array of structs (`[]img_files{string, string, string, string}`). When I insert only 1 struct, the query works fine. But when I want to insert two at once (an array of 2 elements), I got `row value misused` error.

Comment: The learn how to properly construct an array see [Array Constructors](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) and [Array Value Input](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT). And at the bottom of the second link you'll find this tip: *"The ARRAY constructor syntax (see Section 4.2.12) is often easier to work with than the array-literal syntax when writing array values in SQL commands. In ARRAY, individual element values are written the same way they would be written when not members of an array."*

Comment: And if you're curious as to why the error says "row value misused", you should read [Constructing Composite Values](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.6).